# Text Game Commands Parsing?

Tags: python, nlp

I'm interested in writing a parsing engine such as the ones in Inform, which is very robust.

I've tried a couple of different approach:

- regex. For regex, I can only match `{verb} {noun1 optional-noun2} {optional-preposition} {indirect-noun1 optional-indirect-noun2}` This doesn't work that well.
- list of predefined verbs and their matched preposition and nouns. This approach is too complex, since there has to be A LOT of predefined data.
- splitting into different words and run them through a dictionary maps. Again this is too complex and not practical due to the amiguity of certain words such as "look" or "put (on, out)"

I know about language processing though I have actually no idea how to start and some of the stuff are too complicated. (No CS background, I'm just learning on my own right now).

Some ideas I have:

- As I've said, natural language processing.
- Design a parser that parses something similar to SQL.

Is there any other ideas? How would I go about design and implementing them?

Note I'm using Python as my language. and in case you missed it, I'm not design a programming language, I'm just parsing user command such as "go north" or complex stuff, like "put the fire out with the blanket"

Comment: You might want to look at the pyparsing module pyparsing.wikispaces.com

Comment: I feel like writing my own parser would benefit me more as I would learn much more.

Comment: My whole point is to write the pyparsing module so I can learn how it's done.

Comment: Im all for writing to learn but without the background its more of a monumental challenge, whats wrong with reading the source code of pyparsing and then making changes there. you will learn alot more that way

Comment: I see your point, but I'm all for a good challange. I'll definitely take your suggestion, but reading other's code quiet tedious, and reading it without things like design specifications that explains the code, never mind that some code may or may not be commented.

Comment: Please download the pyparsing source package, and check out the included adventure game presentation from PyCon'06. Pyparsing also comes with UML class diagrams, and the adventure parser presentation describes the various classes in UML also. Pyparsing will help you get the kinks out of your grammar definitions and execution, and then if you really want to write your own parser for it, you'll at least have a decent prototype/roadmap to work from.

Comment: See Duncan McGreggor's recent work in this area also: https://launchpad.net/myriad-worlds

Comment: Ah, from another comment, I see that you have found a version of the PyCon presentation - I thought there was a version with UML diagrams out there, but I may be mistaken - it *was* 5 years ago!

Comment: @Ulitmatebuster: For what it's worth, I undertook this exact project a little over a year ago, to try to learn some things about parsing. As a side project it's HARD. If you're already proficient at python/programming generally, and just want to learn about parsing, go for it (And here's an intersting if not immediately useful link: http://sigusr2.net/2011/Apr/18/parser-combinators-made-simple.html). If you're trying to learn python, I would say stick with something simple, if only for now. Best of luck.

Comment: I'm already proficient at Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the mentioned [`pyparsing`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/), which looks very appropriate (I've only used it a tiny bit), you should look into using [`nltk`](http://www.nltk.org/). It's a great collection of tools for natural language processing, and there's even a [book](http://www.nltk.org/book).

Comment: Yeah I saw this too: http://www.gnu-darwin.org/www001/ports-1.5a-CURRENT/devel/py-parsing/work/pyparsing-1.4.5/docs/pycon06-AdventureEngineUsingPyparsing-notes.pdf

Comment: `pyparsing` is hardly appropriate, as it creates recursive descent parsers. When your grammar has only the least bit of ambiguity (which any NL parser will soon have), it will come to a grinding halt; I've seen that happen. Go with NLTK instead.